# The benefit of declaring disposable objects right before using construct

Tags: c#

I am reading a [Logging Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/samples/SampleApp/Program.cs) and I noticed the `LoggerFactory` is defined outside `using`.

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder
        .AddConsole()
        .AddEventLog();
});

// Make sure to dispose ILoggerFactory
using (loggerFactory)
{
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

    logger.LogInformation("Starting");
}
```

## Question

The most commonly used pattern is as follows.

```
using(var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(...))
{
...
}
```

What is the benefit of declaring a disposable object outside `using` and then making it get disposed automatically by `using`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What is the benefit of declaring a disposable object outside using and then making it get disposed automatically by using?*

Not much, I don't think.

Declaring it within the `using` clause would seem more sensible because you'll get compile errors if you accidentally try and use it outside of the `using` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of in your specific case is readability.

Answer (score 1):

It's readability. It would be harder to read if it looked like this:

```
using (var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AddConsole()
            .AddEventLog();
    }))
{
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

    logger.LogInformation("Starting");
}
```

If it takes an extra few seconds to mentally parse that and it can be simpler then it should be simpler. Although, as mentioned in other answers, it means you can have an object that has been disposed but is still in scope. `using` combines the two, making sure it goes out of scope when it's disposed.

Now you can use those extra few seconds to figure out why it's using a static class to create a factory and calling the factory to create a logger instead of just injecting the logger.

Comment: I am searching a console application  sample that shows how to use DI, `ILogger`, `ILoggerProvider`, `ILoggerFactory` to log to a file. Unfortunately, as far as I know, most examples are about Asp.net Core.

Comment: I have a to-do item to create a blog post on using DI in a console app. The short version is to create a `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection`, configure it with all your dependencies (including the logger and the class you want to inject into), calling `CreateServiceProvider` to create the provider, and resolving your class from the `ServiceProvider`. You would add the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection NuGet package to be able to use those classes.

Comment: I did the skeleton as you mentioned above but I don't know how to configure further so I can log to a file. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think they are doing like this for the readability of the initialisation.

I would be against this this syntax, because the lifetime of the object is not bind to the `using` context.
For me, there is a risk of using the object after it was disposed. And maybe one day, you would have an error before the using block, so the object would not be disposed.

In my opinion, you should move the initialisation of the object inside another method, and calling it inside the `using` instruction.

**EDIT**
After reading the sample, I have realized I should have remember you the following thing : This is a **sample**. It is made like this, to fit in a one file program, in the main method.
So definitely, I think it would be better to extract the instanciation in a external method and call it in the `using` instruction to keep the lifetime of the object in the context of the using.